# How to solve: In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use this code but it does not work the way it supposed to be.

```
xp=2;yp=2;
x=[xp;yp];
Vf=[1;1];
N   = 100;
for i = 1:N
    x_Px(i) = x + sqrt(Vf) * randn;
end
```

when I run it gives the error message:

> In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

what should I do?

Comment: `x_Px(i)` is a scalar (1x1) and `x + sqrt(Vf) * randn` is a vector (2x1)

Comment: so how can i change    `x_Px(i)`     into  (2x1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe initialize x_Px as vector? (f. ex. x_Px=[1, 1]) and then use x_Px(i,:)